# Digital Clock Label in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Been playing with python for the past 6 weeks or so and I've been trying to pick up kivy for the past two. Having a real hard time figuring out how to update the label I'm using to display the time in my app.

I've had a look at the crude clock already on here for the incredibly crude clock which is all fine and well, but it returns a label and not the root widget:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

import time

class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = time.asctime()

class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        crudeclock = IncrediblyCrudeClock()
        Clock.schedule_interval(crudeclock.update, 1)
        return crudeclock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

Here's my code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import time

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')

global clocktext

class v3Widget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ClockText(Label):
    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = time.strftime('%I'+':'+'%M'+' %p')
        return ClockText

class v3App(App):
    def build(self):
        clocktext = ClockText()
        Clock.schedule_interval(clocktext.update, 1)
        return v3Widget()

if __name__=="__main__":
    v3App().run()
```

Here's the Kivy:

```
<v3Widget>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1,0.85
            Label:
                text: App.ClockText
                size_hint: 0.75,1
            Button:
                text: 'not clicked'
                size_hint: 0.25,1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            Button:
                text: '1'
            Button:
                text: '2'
            Button:
                text: '3'
            Button:
                text: '4'
            Button:
                text: '5'
```

Any suggestions on how to get that clock label to update every minute would be much appreciated. the closest I could get was setting a variable to clocktext and having it load on start up but wouldn't change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sent the wrong instance to `Clock.interval`. you should send the want that was created in the `kv file`

```
class ClockText(Label):
    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = time.strftime('%I'+':'+'%M'+' %p')

def build(self):
    v3w = v3Widget()
    clocktext = v3w.ids.clocktext
    Clock.schedule_interval(clocktext.update, 1)
    return v3w
```

also create an ID in the kv file:

```
<ClockText>:

<v3Widget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1,0.85
            ClockText: # <--------- !!!
                id: clocktext 
                size_hint: 0.75,1
            Button:
                text: 'not clicked'
                size_hint: 0.25,1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            Button:
                text: '1'
            Button:
                text: '2'
            Button:
                text: '3'
            Button:
                text: '4'
            Button:
                text: '5'
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was what I was attempting to accomplish but couldn't quite make it there. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your label that shows the time should be an instance of `ClockText` class. You have several possibilities, for example:

- **main.py**:

  ```
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.config import Config
  from kivy.clock import Clock
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
  from kivy.uix.label import Label
  from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

  import time

  Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
  Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')


  class V3Widget(BoxLayout):
      clock_label = ObjectProperty()

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(V3Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          Clock.schedule_interval(self.clock_label.update, 1)


  class ClockLabel(Label):
      def update(self, *args):
          self.text = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')


  class V3App(App):
      def build(self):
          return V3Widget()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      V3App().run()
  ```
- **v3.kv**:

  ```
  <V3Widget>
      clock_label: clock_label
      orientation: 'vertical'

      BoxLayout:
          orientation: 'horizontal'
          size_hint: 1,0.85

          ClockLabel:
              id: clock_label
              size_hint: 0.75,1

          Button:
              text: 'Not clicked'
              size_hint: 0.25,1

      BoxLayout:
          orientation: 'horizontal'
          size_hint: 1,0.15

          Button:
              text: '1'

          Button:
              text: '2'

          Button:
              text: '3'

          Button:
              text: '4'

          Button:
              text: '5'
  ```

You could also make your label update itself if it's only going to show the time:

- **main.py** (same kv as in the previous example):

  ```
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.config import Config
  from kivy.clock import Clock
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
  from kivy.uix.label import Label

  import time

  Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
  Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')


  class V3Widget(BoxLayout):
      pass


  class ClockLabel(Label):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(ClockLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

      def update(self, *args):
          self.text = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')


  class V3App(App):
      def build(self):
          return V3Widget()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      V3App().run()
  ```

You don't need to use a global variable, however you are doing it wrong: To use global variables inside a function, you need to do `global <varName>` **inside the function/method**, not when you declares it.